# When I clicked Button then Cursor should move to next EditText in diffrent Frame?

Tags: android, xml, button, android-edittext

I have 4 edittext and 1 button.When i clicked Button then Cursor will go Blank Edittext in next Frame. 
Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) { 
      groupno =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
      start=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);          
      end=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4); 
      groupno.setEnabled(false); 
      start.setEnabled(false); 
      end.setEnabled(false);
    } 
}
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      
    
 public void onClick(View v) {
      
       
 
            
        groupno =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             
 start=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
 end=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);      
      
  groupno.setEnabled(false);
         start.setEnabled(false);
         end.setEnabled(false);
}
}

Comment: @andruboy when i click submit button.It should go to next blank edittext where i take same as 4 blank edit text and button.

Comment: @andruboy  have u find any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this inside the setonlick method.U can use this code to move any edittext.

nextEdittext.requestfocus();

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your button click.

```
View view = getCurrentFocus().focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
int id = view.getId();
if (id != View.NO_ID) {
    findViewById(id).requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code : 
use outside button click -- 
EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
and on button click press :--

```
   ButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            countryText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            countryText.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```